# JavaScript | Is it better to use Function and onclick ="" , than addEventListener("click",{}) for website speed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Background: Very new in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, just started 3 months ago. I am currently making a blog website for a challenge.

Question: I am very concerned how slow my website would be when I publish it, when it comes to website performance or speed, is it better to use Function and onclick ="", than addEventListener("click",{})? Or it doesn't matter at all?

Example 1

HTML:

```
<p popUp1> SecretMessage </p>
<button onclick="pop-up">Click to toggle me on and off</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function pop-up(){
const popUp1 = document.querySelector("[popUp1]")
popUp1.classList.toggle("hide")
}
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

---

Example 2

HTML:

```
<p popUp1> SecretMessage </p>
<button toggleHide>Click to toggle me on and off</button>
```

JavaScript

```
const toggleHide = document.querySelector("[toggleHide]")
const popUp1 = document.querySelector("[popUp1]")

toggleHide.addEventListener("click", (e){
popUp1.classList.toggle("hide")
})
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You are not going to notice any differences. Both methods will be extremely fast. Most websites even use libraries on top of Javascript, such as jQuery, which tends to be slower than plain Javascript anyway. Don't worry about these micro optimizations yet as you are just starting out.

Comment: Performance isn't enough of a difference to worry about. However you should ***always*** use unobtrusive event handlers (i.e. `addEventListener()` in this case) as they are *far* better practice in terms of coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent. The speed difference (assuming there is one) would probably differentiate about 0.5 to 1 ms, which doesn't matter in the long run since that speed is not viewable to any human eye.

Just use whichever you like best and it will work just fine.